# Error al implementar ViewModel Factory - Android Studio - has no zero argument constructor

Tags: android-studio, android-viewmodel

Tengo una clase ViewModel que en su constructor tiene argumentos, por lo que lei, siempre la clase viewmodel su constructor debe estar vacio pero en caso que se quiera pasar argumentos se debe utilizar `ViewModel.Factory` y eso es lo que estoy haciendo en base a la guia de un post que encontre en internet pero me sale la siguiente excepcion:

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.proyecto.view_model.acceso.iniciar_sesion.ViewModelIniciarSesion> has no zero argument constructor
```

Al parecer sigo teniendo problemas de argumentos en el constructor pero no se porque si supuestamente esta era la solucion. Alguien que me ayude a solucionar este problema, aqui les dejo mis clases:

FragmentIniciarSesion.java:

```
public class FragmentIniciarSesion extends Fragment implements ListenerIniciarSesion{

//region Variables
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
private FragmentIniciarSesionBinding binding;
private CustomViewModelFactory factory;
private ViewModelIniciarSesion viewModelIniciarSesion = new ViewModelIniciarSesion(this);
//endregion

public FragmentIniciarSesion() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static FragmentIniciarSesion newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentIniciarSesion fragment = new FragmentIniciarSesion();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_iniciar_sesion, container,false);
    viewModelIniciarSesion = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ViewModelIniciarSesion.class);
    binding.setEventos(viewModelIniciarSesion);
    binding.setCredenciales(viewModelIniciarSesion);
    return binding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

//region Metodos

@Override
public void OnListenerAtras() {
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}

@Override
public void OnListenerMostrarContrasena() {
    binding.imgbtnContrasena.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility_grey50_20dp);
    binding.edtxtContrasena.setTransformationMethod(null);
}

@Override
public void OnListenerOcultarContrasena() {
    binding.imgbtnContrasena.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_visibility_off_grey50_20dp);
    binding.edtxtContrasena.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
}

@Override
public void OnListenerIngresar() {
}

@Override
public void OnListenerOlvidasteTuContrasena() {
    ((ActivityAcceso)getActivity()).reemplazarFragment("recuperar_contrasena_buscar_cuenta");
}

@Override
public void mostrarProgressBar() {
    binding.progbarIniciarSesion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void ocultarProgressBar() {
    binding.progbarIniciarSesion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void mostrarMensajeOk(String mensaje) {
    Utilitarios.mostrarMensajeOk(mensaje, getView().getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), getLayoutInflater());
}

@Override
public void mostrarMensajeError(String mensaje) {
    Utilitarios.mostrarMensajeError(mensaje, getView().getRootView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), getLayoutInflater());
}
//endregion
}
```

ViewModelIniciarSesion.java:

```
public class ViewModelIniciarSesion extends ViewModel{

//region Variables
private String correo_electronico;
private String contrasena;
private InteractorIniciarSesion interactorIniciarSesion;
private ListenerIniciarSesion listenerIniciarSesion;
private boolean mostrarContrasena = false;
private boolean usuarioValido = false;
//endregion

//region Constructor
public ViewModelIniciarSesion(ListenerIniciarSesion listenerIniciarSesion){
    this.correo_electronico = "";
    this.contrasena = "";
    this.listenerIniciarSesion = listenerIniciarSesion;
}
//endregion

//region Getters and Setters
public String getCorreo_electronico() {
    return correo_electronico;
}

public void setCorreo_electronico(String correo_electronico) {
    if(correo_electronico != ""){
        this.correo_electronico = correo_electronico;
    }
}

public String getContrasena() {
    return contrasena;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena) {
    if(contrasena != ""){
        this.contrasena = contrasena;
    }
}
//endregion

//region Metodos
private boolean verificarVacio(){
    if((correo_electronico.replace(" ","") == "" || correo_electronico.isEmpty()) ||
            (contrasena.replace(" ", "") == "" || contrasena.isEmpty())){
        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

public void setOnListener(String tag) {
    switch (tag){
        case "atras":
            listenerIniciarSesion.OnListenerAtras();
            break;

        case "mostrar_contrasena":
            if(!mostrarContrasena){
                mostrarContrasena = true;
                listenerIniciarSesion.OnListenerMostrarContrasena();
            }else{
                mostrarContrasena = false;
                listenerIniciarSesion.OnListenerOcultarContrasena();
            }
            break;

        case "ingresar":
            listenerIniciarSesion.mostrarProgressBar();
            if(!verificarVacio()){
                if(usuarioValido()){
                    listenerIniciarSesion.ocultarProgressBar();
                    listenerIniciarSesion.mostrarMensajeOk("Usuario valido.");
                }else{
                    listenerIniciarSesion.ocultarProgressBar();
                    listenerIniciarSesion.mostrarMensajeError("Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto(s).");
                }
            }else{
                listenerIniciarSesion.ocultarProgressBar();
                listenerIniciarSesion.mostrarMensajeError("Completa todos los campos.");
            }
            break;

        case "olvidaste_tu_contrasena":
            listenerIniciarSesion.OnListenerOlvidasteTuContrasena();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

private boolean usuarioValido(){
    interactorIniciarSesion = new InteractorIniciarSesion(correo_electronico, contrasena);
    interactorIniciarSesion.credencialesValidos(new InteractorIniciarSesion.resultado() {
        @Override
        public void resultado(boolean resultado) {
            if(resultado){
                usuarioValido = true;
            }else{
                usuarioValido = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return usuarioValido;
}
//endregion
}
```

CustomViewModelFactory.java:

```
public class CustomViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {
private ListenerIniciarSesion listenerIniciarSesion;

public CustomViewModelFactory(ListenerIniciarSesion listenerIniciarSesion) {
    this.listenerIniciarSesion = listenerIniciarSesion;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    return super.create(modelClass);
}
}
```

ListenerIniciarSesion.java:

```
public interface ListenerIniciarSesion{
void OnListenerAtras();
void OnListenerMostrarContrasena();
void OnListenerOcultarContrasena();
void OnListenerIngresar();
void OnListenerOlvidasteTuContrasena();
void mostrarProgressBar();
void ocultarProgressBar();
void mostrarMensajeOk(String mensaje);
void mostrarMensajeError(String mensaje);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu **CustomViewModelFactory**, el metodo que crea el **ViewModel** debería retornar lo siguiente:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    return <T>new ViewModelIniciarSesion(listenerIniciarSesion);
}
}
```